# Attach Pycharm's remote debugger to two containers simultaneously

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I use Pycharm to develop a Django app which relies on Celery for background tasks. For debugging, I use PyCharm's remote interpreter. I configured a [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html) with a [remote interpreter using docker-compose](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) to start the `django` service. I can launch this run configuration with an attached debugger and it will break at breakpoints. When launching, Pycharm will start all other services via docker-compose.

I would like to attach the debugger to the `django` *and* `celery` services at the same time so that it interrupts at breakpoints also when the celery worker comes across them.

I already tried to configure another docker-compose remote interpreter using the `celery` service. But launching one terminates the other.

**Edit**: If it's not possible with PyCharm, then maybe VS Code can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config) you can specify 2 debug configurations distinguished by port number.

Also you can combine 2 independed ways "[deployment configuration for a remote interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-interpreter)" simultanously with
"[remote debug server configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config)"

Answer (score 1):

On VS Code the feature you are looking for is called [Compound launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations)